# data.frame Select columns with condition

Tags: r

I have 2 questions but they are very similar:

1) I have a dataframe: `test<-data.frame(NAT1=1,NAT2=2,NAT3=3,NAT_S1=4,NAT_S2=5)`:

```
  NAT1 NAT2 NAT3 NAT_S1 NAT_S2
1    1    2    3      4      5
```

I want to select column which names start with NAT and end with a number:

```
  NAT1 NAT2 NAT3 
1    1    2    3
```

2) Same thing I want to do with characters: `colnames(test)`
I want to keep only : `[1] "NAT1" "NAT2" "NAT3"`

I suppose there are a function could do this.
Thanks for your help

Comment: What's the difference between the first task and the second?

Comment: @camille The last 2 column names end with S1 and S2 : letters and numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
test[, grepl("^NAT\\d$", names(test))]
  NAT1 NAT2 NAT3
1    1    2    3
```

If you have more than 1 number after `NAT`, you can use the quantifier `+` or, if you want to select a certain number of numbers or a certain range of numbers, quantification with `{ }`:

```
test[, grepl("^NAT\\d+$", names(test))] # matches one or more numbers
test[, grepl("^NAT\\d{2}$", names(test))] # matches exactly 2 numbers
test[, grepl("^NAT\\d{2,4}$", names(test))] # matches the range of 2 to 4 numbers
test[, grepl("^NAT\\d{2,}$", names(test))] # matches the range of 2 to any number of numbers
```

Alternatively, you can use `str_detect`from the package `stringr`:

```
test[, str_detect(colnames(test), "^NAT\\d$")]
  NAT1 NAT2 NAT3
1    1    2    3
```

Comment: thank you, if I have column names with 2 numbers after NAT how could that function work? like I have ```NAT11  NAT12```

Comment: I've edited the answer to include answers to your new question.

Comment: thank you! that works perfectly.  I wonder what was the meaning with thoses expressions: ```"^xxxx\\d+$"```

Comment: Not sure why you ask this. But `"^xxxx\\d+$"` matches 4 times `x`(the first of which must occur at the beginning of a string) followed by one or more numbers (the last of which must occur at the end of the string), e.g., `xxxx2`or `xxxx123456789`.

Comment: I've edited the answer again to include even more options.

Answer (score 0):

With `dplyr`, we can use `matches`

```
library(dplyr)
test %>%
   select(matches("^NAT.*\\d+$"))
```